# pipe if on variable which is either numeric or undefined

Tags: javascript

I got this line of code:

```
htmlTmp += htmlTDX.replace('#FIELD#', checkoutToday[b].deposit);
```

Now checkoutToday[b].deposit will either hold a numeric value, or it will be undefined.

I do not want it to say "undefined" but just blank or 0 if undefined.

If there a way to do this in one line?  Or is my only option:

```
if (checkoutToday[b].deposit) {
    htmlTmp += htmlTDX.replace('#FIELD#', checkoutToday[b].deposit);
} else {
    htmlTmp += htmlTDX.replace('#FIELD#', 0);
}
```

Comment: `.replace('#FIELD#', checkoutToday[b].deposit || 0)`... What's not to get? :D

Comment: A bit of searching could have given you the answer. Let me find a duplicate...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thanks - didnt know it was that simple :)  So what it mean is actually if first expression is true then show it and if its false, then show the other. Is that correct?

Comment: @trincot I did - but I couldnt make mine work from the other examples. I just realized I did it with one pipe instead of double pipe.